# Reading Java UUID (from DB) in C#

Tags: c#, java, .net, uuid

I'm trying to map a table, where one of the column is a binary array (which is a Java UUID), to a C# class.

I would like to read the byte array and return a string representation of the UUID. Just wondering what's a good place to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've already got it as a byte array, then just call [`new Guid(bytes)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/90ck37x3(v=VS.90).aspx) to get a `Guid`; you can call `ToString` on that to convert it to a string if you particularly need to. (I'd suggest leaving it as a `Guid` though other than for diagnostics.)